# How to Throw a Custom Exception When Bean Validation In Spring Boot with Hibernate Validator Fails?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.1 with inclusion of validation-starter (which comes with **Hibernate Validation 6.x**) and trying to validate a method parameter and return objects in my Spring repository layer. There are basically a `ParamObj` and `ReturnObj` for this method,

```
@Repository
@Validated // Spring integration of validation
public class MyRepoImpl implements MyRepo {

  @Override
  @Valid
  public ReturnObj myMethod(@Valid ParamObj param) throw CustomException {
    try {
       // makes a call that might throw an exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new CustomException(/*...*/, e);
    }

    return returnObj;
  }
}
```

`ParamObj` and `ReturnObj` both use a simple set of Bean Validation annotations on some of their properties, e.g `@Pattern`, `@Min`, etc.. My problem is that with these annotations, if either `ParamObj` or `ReturnObj` fails the validation process, `MyRepoImpl#myMethod()` would throw `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`.

However, as you can see, the contract for `myMethod()` mandates to throw a `CustomException`. Yes, `ConstraintViolationException` is a `RuntimeException`, however, now the caller of `MyRepoImpl#myMethod()`, e.g. a service layer logic, needs to catch this `RuntimeException` in addition to `CustomException`.

And the reason is, I need to **prevent** all the exceptions from bubbling **out of the service layer** (for this particular Spring `@Service` I have which calls this repository) -- this service is part of a long list of services that are called via a service orchestration which constructs a larger encompassing object. In other word, this piece (result coming obtained via `MyRepoImpl`) is considered **optional**, and subsequently, its failure should only be logged but **do not stop the whole process**.

For that reason, I can't utilize `ControllerAdvice` to capture `ConstraintViolationException` for the entire application.

My goal is to be able, when the validation fails for either method parameter or return, to throw only `CustomException` back to the caller.

Is this possible with annotations only? I looked into `MethodValidationPostProcessor` but can't figure out if I can implement my own to accomplish this goal.

P.S. The only way I can think to achieve this is to forgo `@Valid`/`@Validated` and call `Validator#validate(obj, ...)` programmatically for the parameter and return value inside the `try-catch` block, catch the constraint exception, and throw my `CustomException()`. However, I want to know if I can avoid that and leave this hard coded validation out of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not here a year ago I would not have answered but since this is a common question as I can see through my experience with fellow students, I think the answer might be @ControllerAdvice, comes handy with any type of exceptions
doc --> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html

Comment: A `ControllerAdvice` class only captures `ConstraintViolationException`. The question is, how one can throw a custom exception instead of define one for these validation errors?

Comment: ControllerAdvice catches any type of exception that extends Runtime.

Comment: Yes, and that's not what the question here. Please reread the entire content.